# Xslt transform types declared in xs:import schema

Tags: xslt

I need to transform a xsd, which represents Java dtos into html.
The main goal is the allowed to fill the object even in production if the regular input fails. (i.e., it doesn't need to be pretty)

I found https://github.com/MichielCM/xsd2html2xml which should do exactly what I want, but unfortunately doesn't.

My problem is the following: If I have a source schema like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:c="http://www.trivia/commonTypes/v1_0"
       targetNamespace="http://www.trivia/v1_0" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0">

<xs:import schemaLocation="comm.xsd" namespace="http://www.trivia/commonTypes/v1_0" />

<xs:element name="common" type="c:typeAddress"/>
<xs:element name="local" type="typeAddress"/>
<xs:element name="simple" type="xs:string"/>

<xs:complexType name="typeAddress">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="city" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="40" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

the simple and local elements are transformed as expected, but the common element is not. The comm.xsd contains a copy of typeAdress for the sake of the example.

The question is how can I reference a type declared with an import statement in a xsl transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing any kind of processing that starts from source XSD documents is a tough undertaking, because there are so many ways of expressing things: do you need to handle named attribute groups or model groups, for example? What about xs:redefines? You can always extend a bit of software like this to handle one more case, but you're on an uphill escalator: there's always going to be a lot more to do before you're finished. My advice is, don't do it this way. Use an API that gives you access to the internal schema component model built by a schema processor. The Xerces processor exposes this via a Java API, the Saxon processor exposes it as an XML document (called an SCM file). Either way all the surface stuff like xs:import is taken care of and you only need worry about the underlying data model.